# How can I convert an unsigned char array into a base64 string?

Tags: c, arrays, string, base64

I have a large buffer array of type `unsigned char buffer[2850]` that I would like to convert to a Base64 string. I'm trying to use the libb64 library which can be found [on github](https://github.com/cburstedde/libsc/tree/master/libb64)

Here is how I'm trying to convert it:

```
char* encode(const char* input)
{
    /* set up a destination buffer large enough to hold the encoded data */
    char* output = (char*)malloc(SIZE);
    /* keep track of our encoded position */
    char* c = output;
    /* store the number of bytes encoded by a single call */
    int cnt = 0;
    /* we need an encoder state */
    base64_encodestate s;

    /*---------- START ENCODING ----------*/
    /* initialise the encoder state */
    base64_init_encodestate(&s);
    /* gather data from the input and send it to the output */
    cnt = base64_encode_block(input, strlen(input), c, &s);
    c += cnt;
    /* since we have encoded the entire input string, we know that
     there is no more input data; finalise the encoding */
    cnt = base64_encode_blockend(c, &s);
    c += cnt;
    /*---------- STOP ENCODING  ----------*/

    /* we want to print the encoded data, so null-terminate it: */
    *c = 0;

    return output;
}

char *encodedBuffer;
encodedBuffer = encode(buffer);
```

but I'm getting the warning

```
Passing 'unsigned char [2850]' to parameter of type 'const char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign.
```

Is there a better way to convert it or is there something I need to alter since I'm trying to pass in an unsigned char array. Thanks!

Comment: `encodedBuffer = encode((const char*)buffer);`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I'm really new to C, does adding (const char*) in front of the buffer dynamically change the type?

Comment: `unsigned char *buffer[2850]` isn't an array of unsigned char; its an array of 2850 **pointers**. if that isn't your real code, post it.

Comment: It just tells the compiler that it's ok to handle the `unsigned char[2850]` as a `const char*` in this case. Basically it tells the compiler "I know what I'm doing, so don't bug me about it", so if you're a beginner you should know that it's not always safe to just cast any type to any other like this.

Comment: @Stavros_S Where does the `encoode()` function come from? I cannot find it in the sources.

Comment: `char *unsignedBuffer; encodedBuffer = encode(buffer);` and the posted error do not make sense.  Are you sure this is your code?

Comment: @chux sorry fixed the code for that and also added in the function declaration for encode()

Comment: See @ Joachim Isaksson initial comment.  Depending on other factors you may want `strlen(input)+1` in `base64_encode_block()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your buffer is of type `char**`. You need to pass one of type `char*`.

You can use

```
const char *buffer = "whatever";
encode(buffer);
```

Comment: Will that work though if my buffer is an array of hex values (it's an array of bytes)

Comment: @Stavros_S you can use `strncpy` to copy your hex to the `char*`

Comment: the hex values are stored in the array buffer which is declared as 'unsigned char buffer[2850]' I don't think strncpy would allow me to do this due to the buffer not being a const char.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a large buffer array of type unsigned char *buffer[2850] that I would like to convert

```
char * buffer[2850];
```

is an array of 2850 pointers to `char`.

I doubt this is what you want.

Use

```
char buffer[2850] = ""; /* The = "" inits the array to all 0s, that is to the empty string "". */
```

to define a character array of the 2850 elements, that is a C-"string" to hold 2849 `char`s plus the `0`-terminator.

---

Referring to the question's title "*... convert an unsigned char array ...*" Please note that it depends on the compiler in use whether a variable declared as `char` will be treated `signed` or `unsigned`. So to be sure better be explicit:

```
unsigned char buffer[2850] = "";
```

Comment: Appreciate the advice. I have implemented what you mention hereyet when I try to log out the newly encoded buffer using %s nothing displays. I'm building this in xcode for OSX.

Comment: @Stavros_S: You are welcome. As the problem you are facing now is different from this question you might like to pose a another, a new question on your current issue.